# Trigger abort insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

When I create this trigger the insert in the table recensione doesn't work anymore.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `premium` AFTER INSERT ON `recensione` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE n INT;
DECLARE g VARCHAR(255);
SET n = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recensione WHERE id_autore=NEW.id_autore);
SET g = (SELECT gruppo FROM utente WHERE id=NEW.id_autore);
IF (n >= 20 AND g != `Amministratore`) THEN
UPDATE utente AS u SET u.gruppo=`Premium` WHERE u.id=NEW.id_autore;
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the status report on your current efforts. I'm not sure if you were asking a question, but in case you were, this line looks wrong.

```
IF (n >= 20 AND g != `Amministratore`) THEN
                     ^              ^
```

It looks like you want to compare the contents of local variable `g` with a literal value, but a literal value is enclosed in single quotes, not backticks. backticks are used for identifiers (table names, column names, etc.)

```
IF (n >= 20 AND g != 'Amministratore') THEN
                     ^              ^
```

Same goes for this line:

```
UPDATE utente AS u SET u.gruppo=`Premium` WHERE u.id=NEW.id_autore;
                                ^       ^
```

Looks like you want to set the column to a literal value, not the value of another column in the `utente` table.

```
UPDATE utente AS u SET u.gruppo='Premium' WHERE u.id=NEW.id_autore;
                                ^       ^
```

Comment: Thak you very much. Sorry for my bad english!